# Browser Console - How to include javascript code on every page redirect?

Tags: browser, console, include

Is is possible to load special javascript code (created by me) to my browser console (mozilla firefox) on every redirect page? I want to create a special script-robot, which will be do special actions on some website. For example:

1. Click button: "Add new advert"

... NOW IS REDIRECT

2. Write to input[name='title'] advert title
3. Write to input[name='description'] advert description
4. Click button: "Add now!"

... NOW IS REDIRECT

5. Click button: "Logout".

So I want to include my own javascript code to my console and I want automatically reinclude this file on every page redirect. Is is possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, it is possible. What you would do is create your own google extension with links to a js file to run. [Here](https://thoughtbot.com/blog/how-to-make-a-chrome-extension) are some instructions on how to make said extension.